# Admission to graduate school for physics

Tags: graduate-admissions, physics

I am a dual major (Math+Physics) student from one of the reputed Indian University. I want to peruse PhD in physics (mainly theoretical/High Energy Physics). I have CGPA 9.6/10 in Physics but overall (Math+Physics) CGPA is 8/10.
How do I improve my CV to get into good grad school in US/Germany etc?

Any helpful comments/answer are welcome and thanks for that.

Comment: Welcome to Academia.SE. This is quite a broad question, so I'm not sure we can say any more than what has been said here: [How does the admissions process work for Ph.D. programs in the US, particularly for weak or borderline students?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/38237/how-does-the-admissions-process-work-for-ph-d-programs-in-the-us-particularly). The German system is a bit [different](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/43313/why-are-us-phds-different-from-european-phds), but many considerations will be similar.

Comment: @cag51, yes I got some broad Ideas what I need to do. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

I cannot tell you what to do, but it might be worth observing that your written documents at most give an initial impression of "who you are", and that the graduate program will be able to reflect on that initial impression if they are so fortunate as to meet you in person.  Presumably you will have reflected on what information you believe is most relevant to the admissions committee.  To some extent, this might include your perspective on physics (or science more generally), mathematics, the position or role of academia in society, and/or what sort of behavior or personal growth you believe you could sustain over the course of your graduate career, and as much evidence (or more typically a 'clue' to where evidence can be found) is needed to support your claims.  If you are familiar with the basic rules of bridge, it might help to think of your academic goals or dreams as the bid, the admissions committee as your partner, and the limits of your permanent record, ease or effectiveness of respectful collaboration, and/or extempore knowledge (that you might also have an opportunity to share, gracefully, during a visit or interview) as your "opponent".  If you want the strongest possible cross section with the interest of teleologically relevant programs, try to pack as much teleologically relevant and easily verifiable information about yourself as possible.

Comment: I appreciate your answer.